# How to add WTL and ATL to visual studio c++ express 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, atl, wtl

I start using the visual studio c++ express 2008 at home but there is no ATL in it.
How can I add ATL to visual studio c++ express 2008?

Comment: Related: [C++ #include <atlbase.h> is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3898287/3357935)

Answer (score 23):

ATL 7.1 is now part of the [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/WDK/WDKpkg.mspx).

Comment: Looks like the link is now dead.

Answer (score 9):

ATL was only included in older versions of the SDK. Recent versions of ATL share much code with MFC and are only available with the real versions of Visual Studio, i.e. not with VS Express.

So: to use ATL and/or MFC, you need to buy the Professional version of Visual Studio. If you are content with old versions of ATL, you can download old versions of the platform SDK from the Microsoft website.

Answer (score 4):

http://codegem.org/2008/09/wtl-wizard-for-visual-studio-2008

In his modified script, replace VisualStudio to VCExpress.

Comment: Link looks like it should point to http://blog.technicallyworks.com/2009/04/installing-wtl-wizard-in-visual-c-2008.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to download the platform SDK and muck around with some dependencies to get ATL.

There might be some more "unsavory" ways to get MFC ;) if you catch my drift.  Also many institutions have educational VS licenses which are free.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install Windows Platform SDK as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/WTLExpress.aspx)