# How to create MFC applications with VS express08?

Tags: mfc

How do you create MFC applications with Visual Studio express '08?

Answer (score 3):

Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition does not support MFC. You need at least the Standard or Professional edition of Visual Studio. Refer to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9.aspx) for a comparison of the various editions.

If you want to develop native Windows GUI aplications using the Express Edition, you could consider using WTL. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659/how-to-add-wtl-and-atl-to-visual-studio-c-express-2008) for more information.