# GUI App with Visual C++ Express Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2008, user-interface, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-express

What tool (preferably free) can be used with Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition to create Win32 GUI applications? As you know the Express Edition does not include a GUI resource editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't, but that doesn't stop you from creating a Win32 GUI app; you can still do this in code.

If that's unappealing for you, just do a Google search for "win32 Resource Editor." There are a few available. Any tool that creates .rc files can be compiled into your C++ project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Win32 GUI applications using the [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/), [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), or [Qt](http://trolltech.com/) libraries, among others. These have been discussed before in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115045/good-c-gui-library-for-windows) on StackOverflow. Note that, as I answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316071/how-to-create-mfc-applications-with-vs-express08), the Express Edition does not include MFC, so that's not an option for you.

I hope that someone else will be able to recommend a good resource editor.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat different from your answer, because it cannot be used with Visual C++, but check out wxDevC++....it is like visual studios but has the drag and drop window creation that i think you are looking for.