# CImage class in ATL

Tags: c++, c, image, include, atl

I have windows 8 and Micosoft Visual Studio 2010 Express.

I'm working on a project which I need to transfer a picture through client and server. I search a little bit and found CImage class useful.

The Problem is that CImage class is in ATL library and my visual studio doesn't have this library, Is there a way that I can include the ATL library to my VS or download another VS (that can be run on Win8) ?

And if someone knows a better class or library to work with pictures, and bitmaps I would be happy to hear

Answer (score 1):

[ATL is not available in Express version of Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681050/atlbase-h-not-found-when-using-visual-c-express-2010/7885201#7885201). `CImage` class, however, is merely a wrapper over GDI and [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs, which you can use directly.

Comment: The GDI+ seems convenient but when I looked at the internet for examples, the examples used classes like "Image" and "Bitmap" that should be included but I don't have them.. You know what's wrong?

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533958(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into the BITMAP, that is available in Win32 API. A bitmap is a series of points (bits) arranged like a map so that, when put together, they produce a picture that can be written to, copied from, re-arranged, changed, manipulated, or stored as a a computer file. The bitmap can me manipulated through Device Context (HDC).  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azz5wt61.aspx)

Some basic tutorial: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html

Also if you have access to it, the Petzold Programming Windows (5th ed.) has chapter 14 and 15 devoted to bitmaps and graphics.