# ATL development with VC++ 2008 Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, atl

I have recently installed Windows Server 2003 R2 for gaining access to ATL header and library files. I have set the include and library paths in the Visual C++ 2008 Express to compile the ATL code with cl.exe. When I compile the solution in the VC++ 2008 Express.  The following error message comes out.

```
    d:\programs\psdk windows sever 2003\include\atl\atlbase.h(513) : warning C4996:    '_vsnprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

    d:\programs\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdio.h(358) : see declaration of '_vsnprintf'

    d:\programs\psdk windows sever 2003\include\atl\atlbase.h(537) : warning C4996: '_vsnprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

    d:\programs\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdio.h(358) : see declaration of '_vsnprintf'

    d:\programs\psdk windows sever 2003\include\atl\atlbase.h(561) : warning C4996: '_vsnwprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnwprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

    d:\programs\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\wchar.h(719) : see declaration of '_vsnwprintf'

    d:\programs\psdk windows sever 2003\include\atl\atlbase.h(584) : warning C4996: '_vsnwprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnwprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

    d:\programs\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\wchar.h(719) : see declaration of '_vsnwprintf'
    Compiling manifest to resources...
    Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.6723.1
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
    Linking...
    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'atlthunk.lib'
```

Any help would be worth...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add WTL and ATL to visual studio c++ express 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659/how-to-add-wtl-and-atl-to-visual-studio-c-express-2008)

Answer (score -1):

1.find 'atlthunk.lib' whole project,
if find '#pragma comment(lib, "atlthunk.lib")',and delete it.

2.`project setting link -> input->add-on dependency, remove 'atlthunk.lib'`.

Comment: This answer's a little obscure. Not everybody reading this will understand what it does and how it solves the problem Perhaps you could explain a little more for the sake of posterity (and newbie users)? :)