# Where can I get afx...h files?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm developing with an API and the API requires the `afxsock.h` among other `afx...` headers. After searching online, it seems that my VS Express isn't enough, so I looked to purchase the product at microsoft. Unfortunately it's 700$ and as a beginning programmer, it makes no sense for me to drop that on 1 project which I am using to teach myself c++. (I.e. I still don't know if I want to program long term in C++ or another language).

In any case, I was wondering if there was some sort of work around to get the `afx` (or more appropriately the `MFC`) files?

Note that I have Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012, and I've downloaded the Windows Development Kit for Windows 8, but still can't compile because I'm getting missing `afx` errors.

Comment: If you are only just learning programming, afx and MFC are probably not what you want to learn anyway as they are definitely legacy by now. Using VS and Windows 8 there is no way you can get the libraries you need easily.

Comment: @Serdalis I know getting libraries will be tough but my computer recently broke and I had to get a new one, ergo VS2012 express and Windows 8. By legacy do you mean no one uses it anymore?

Comment: @user2151446 I am a self learner. I am trying to learn C++ so that I can develop a trading program with an API from the Interactive Brokers (an online brokerage) trading platform... I have read books on C++ and I am patient, so so far, everything has been understandable. Being "too hard to learn" won't be a factor in my decision to use it...The fact that the API requires it sort of forces my hand to get it...Although at $700 I'm not exactly sure how I can do that...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659/

Comment: @CodyGray although the questions are similar I think this one is a better answer. I was aware it doesn't come with visual studio express as I had found those answers already on stack overflow. However my question is asking where can I get it and also I imply in my question that I am aware VS Express doesn't have it. The answers here are much better than the answers on the other pages as this has provided 3 options for people looking to learn to develop.

Comment: Yes, I agree this question has a better answer. That answer should be posted to the other question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AFX prefix stands for **A**pplication **F**ramework E**x**tensions, which was the original name for the [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) (**M**icrosoft **F**oundation **C**lasses) libraries. The file names were set in stone before the name was changed to MFC, and it was too late to change them.

So you need MFC in order to use those headers. Unfortunately, the Express versions of Visual Studio do not include MFC (or [ATL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library)). You can only develop MFC applications using the Standard, Professional, or higher editions of Visual Studio.

If you are a student, you have a couple of great options:

- You can can join [Microsoft's DreamSpark program](https://www.dreamspark.com/), which is free to students and entitles you to some great free downloads, including VS 2012 Professional, VS 2010 Professional, and recent server versions of Windows.
- Alternatively, you can join the IEEE for a very low cost. The
  IEEE student membership entitles you to download many Microsoft tools, including the *Ultimate* editions of Visual Studio. See [this page](http://www.ieee.org/membership_services/membership/students/students_software.html) for more information. (Although that page mention VS 2010, VS 2012 is actually available.)

Otherwise, you will have to either buy Visual Studio Standard/Professional outright, or join [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/buy.aspx).

Alternatively, you could use the winsock2 API, which is part of the Windows SDK rather than MFC. Get started with the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673.aspx). The Windows SDK is what you're getting when you downloaded the "Windows Development Kit for Windows 8". It includes everything you need to link to native Win32 libraries, but it does not include the MFC framework.

Comment: Dang it, this is a good answer for people starting out. Unfortunately for me, I'm over half a decade out of a school.

Comment: [Microsoft's DreamSpark program](https://www.dreamspark.com/) is also free for students and makes Visual Studio Professional available for download.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it has 2 options but I think people who are interested should also look at Nik Bougalis' answer which is a 3rd option. Hopefully this question will help future students and business people who qualify for the programs

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the IEEE "student membership" option that someone else linked to, you may want to consider Microsoft's [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) program which will give you access to more than just Visual Studio. I do not know if you qualify for it, but it's worth looking into.

---

With that said, it's time to step onto the soapbox and add some commentary: I understand the problem of API of choice having a dependency on MFC, but realistically speaking developing a trading program is neither particularly easy nor a good place for you to start. In addition, starting with MFC is probably not a good idea unless you want to specifically focus on becoming an MFC developer. If you are set on C++ you would be better served focusing your efforts on learning C++11. Or at least learning it *first*. Once you are comfortable with that, then you can focus on learning GUI programming using any of the many frameworks available.

Just my $0.02.

Comment: Thanks for the link that is a useful one and I will be looking to see if I qualify. Also, I have learnt c++11 already so writing the program isn't difficult (I'm using QT for gui which is relatively easy so far), the difficult part will be figuring out an algorithm to trade profitably, but that isn't a programming problem, more of a logic problem. I'm not doing any machine learnin...yet :)  Besides that, my biggest problem is that the API requires including afx which hopefully your link will be somewhere where I can download visual studios. Thanks for your help again!