# MFC in Visual Studio 2012 - afx.h file not found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, stdafx.h, afx

I created an new static library project in VS 2012, with option MFC selected.
It created few files in the project, stdafx.h, targetver.h, stdafx.cpp. However in stdafx.h there are includes for afx.h, afxwin.h etc and they were marked as errors. I can't compile just out of the box solution. It says afx.h file not found. What does this mean?

Comment: The same issue was solved in this link. It may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227840/where-can-i-get-afx-h-files